# Если несобственно-прямая речь сливается с авторским текстом, как ведут себя знаки?

Tags: пунктуация

> ...Иногда выходишь со сцены после спектакля и думаешь: «Как же я
>   хорошо сыграла!», а зритель спрашивает: «Что случилось? Ты не в
>   настроении?» И наоборот – выходишь и чувствуешь: всё кончено, это был
>   отвратительный, **провальный спектакль, и вдруг слышишь** от людей: «Это
>   было лучшее из того, что мы видели!»

Что делает запятая после провального спектакля?

Comment: Какой-то знак там должен быть, видимо, посильнее запятой, чтобы отделить от чувств события. Например, точка с запятой - если не заканчивать в этом месте предложение.

Comment: О! Отточие! )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Весь отрывок построен на антитезе: ты чувствуешь одно, а люди вокруг видят противоположное.Конструкции параллельны. Первое предложение сложносочинённое, там есть противительный союз,а во втором простые соединены союзом И, но противопоставление есть, даже с оттенком неожиданности. В таком случае ставится тире в сложносочинённом, можно даже запятую с тире как единый знак:

*И наоборот – выходишь и чувствуешь: всё кончено, это был отвратительный, провальный спектакль,- и вдруг слышишь от людей: «Это было лучшее из того, что мы видели!»*